# GAMS maximum element

Tags: max, linear-algebra, linear-regression, minimize, gams-math

I have to get [GAMS](http://www.gams.com/) to find the maximum element of a set. This should result in some linear regression model, where the objective is not the least squares but the least maximum deviation.

My data points are the `(x(p), y(p))` points (There is `Set p / p1*p1000 / ;` given). I managed to solve the regression model as described by [amsterdamoptimization](http://amsterdamoptimization.com/statistics.html):

```
Variables
  m            Slope
  b            Constant
  objVal       Objective Value
;

Equations
  objFun       Objective Function
  lin(p)       Regression Model
;

objFun ..      objVal =n= 0;
lin(p) ..      y(p) =e= m * x(p) + b;

option lp=ls;
Model Regression / objFun, lin / ;
Solve Regression minimizing objVal using lp;
```

But what I should hand in is something like

```
Variables
  m            Slope
  b            Constant
  objVal       Objective Value
;

Equations
  objFun       Regression Model
;

objFun ..      objVal =e= smax(p, abs( y(p) - (m * x(p) + b) ));

Model Regression / objFun / ;
Solve Regression minimizing objVal using lp;
```

Of course you can read this, but GAMS hates it:

```
2031  Solve Regression minimizing objVal using lp;
****                                             $51,59,256
Error Messages

 51  Endogenous function argument(s) not allowed in linear models
 59  Endogenous prod smin smax require model type "dnlp"
256  Error(s) in analyzing solve statement. More detail appears
     Below the solve statement above
```

Yep, it is homework, nevertheless I'm completely stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, maximum can be handled easily:

```
objFun ..      objVal =e= smax(p, abs( y(p) - (m * x(p) + b) ));
```

Is equivalent to

```
objFun(p) ..   objVal =g= abs( y(p) - (m * x(p) + b) );
```

Now GAMS doesn't like abs() used in linear models for obvious reasons, but remember `x > abs(y)` means `(x > y) AND (x > -y)`, so:

```
objFun1(p) ..  objVal =g= y(p) - (m * x(p) + b);
objFun2(p) ..  objVal =g= -( y(p) - (m * x(p) + b) );
```

Which is finally (canonical conformity):

```
objFun1(p) ..  objVal + x(p) * m + b =g= y(p);
objFun2(p) ..  objVal - x(p) * m - b =g= -y(p);
```